# STFT for Classification

Tags: python, stft, classification

I am working on this project in which I am using Short Time Fourier Transform (STFT) for feature extraction before applying classification model. I have a time series sensor data, applied signal processing on it to remove noise peaks and then applied STFT for feature extraction. The code that I have used to implement STFT is as follows:

```
features, position, Zpp = signal.stft(sensor data, sampling rate, noverlap=0, nperseg=12)
```

where nperseg has been set in accordance with the length of the component I am trying to classify.

My task is to assign soft labels to each window of the STFT result by comparing the position values with the labeled position values in my data. Next, I will put the features and the soft labeled windows to my classifier for classification. As I am new to feature extraction, can any expert help me in this matter?

P.S. I am trying to classify rail track components such as tongue. If there is a start of tongue against any position value, then it is label as 1 otherwise 0. The tongue example has been shown below:

[image]

The sensor that has been used to collect the data is inductive in nature and records values in accordance with the varying magnetic field.

Comment: Would it be possible to add what sort of sensor you are using?

Comment: Added the type of sensor